# Arrays in webservices - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, initialization

I am sending soap messages that contains arrays. I have problems with arrays in my code. It gives the above errors, I've looked everywhere, even wrote and rewrote my code over and over again but I can't seem to find where I am going wrong.

Would be so grateful if somebody can point me in the right direction:

```
UpdateRatePackages.IService.InventoryServiceClient isc = new UpdateRatePackages.IService.InventoryServiceClient();
    UpdateRatePackages.IService.UpdateRatePackagesRequest ureq = new UpdateRatePackages.IService.UpdateRatePackagesRequest();
    UpdateRatePackages.IService.UpdateRatePackagesOperationResponse ores = new UpdateRatePackages.IService.UpdateRatePackagesOperationResponse();
```

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendSoapMessage();
        }

protected void SendSoapMessage()
        {

```
        Int64 HID = 717759;
        Int64 HRID = 85264;
        int avail = 6;
       // RateDetails.AvailabilityApplicationType val  = RateDetails.AvailabilityApplicationType.SET;
       for (int i = 0; i < ureq.RatePackages.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            ureq.RatePackages[i].RatePackageId = HRID;
            for (int j = 0; j < ureq.RatePackages[j].Rates.GetLength(0); j++)
            {
                ureq.RatePackages[i].Rates[j].Availability = avail;
                ureq.RatePackages[i].Rates[j].AvailabilityApplicationType = UpdateRatePackages.IService.AvailabilityApplicationType.SET;
                ureq.RatePackages[i].Rates[j].FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-03-21");
                ureq.RatePackages[i].Rates[j].ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-03-31");
            }

           // isc.UpdateRatePackages(request);

        }
```

Data Defined as in the webservice:

```
     public class UpdateRatePackagesRequest
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
        public UpdateRatePackageRequest[] RatePackages;


    }

    public class UpdateRatePackageRequest
    {
        public Int64 RatePackageId;
        public RateDetails[] Rates;

    }


    public class RateDetails
    {
        public decimal Rate;
        public enum RateApplicationType { SET, INCREASE, DECREASE, INCREASE_PERCENT, DECREASE_PERCENT } ;
        public int Availability;
        public enum AvailabilityApplicationType { SET , INCREASE, DECREASE };
        public bool StopSell;
        public string Inclusions;
        public int MinimumNightStay;
        public DateTime FromDate;
        public DateTime ToDate;

    }



    public class UpdateRatePackageResult
    {
        public Int64 RatePackageId;
        public Boolean Success;
        public string Message;

    }

    public class UpdateRatePackagesResponse

    {
        public UpdateRatePackageResult[] Result;

    }
```

Is my problem in the arrays or does it have something to do with the soap message itself?

line where error is highlighted:

> for (int i = 0; i < ureq.RatePackages.GetLength(0); i++)

Please help!

Comment: What's the stack trace? Which line is the exception occurring on?

Comment: On line 100 that is the line I have pasted on top in quotes

Comment: OH, got it... ok then either `ureq` or `RatePackages` is `null`, have you tried setting a break point and checking either one of those?

Comment: Yes RatePackages is null, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ureq.RatePackages.GetLength(0); i++)
```

If the error is happening there, then either `ureq` or `RatePackages` is `null`. Step through in the debugger and see which one is `null`. It does look like you're setting `ureq`, but you should check both anyway.

Comment: RatePackages is null, how can I fix that?

Comment: @user1270384 take a look at whatever is supposed to set `RetePackages` and ensure that it's setting it to a valid value. I don't know what your code looks like, so I can't tell you much more than that. May the force be with you! :)

Comment: ok thanks for trying to help. Is there something I may be missing from my code above that I can add to assist you?

Comment: @user1270384 ideally you should be able to create an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) compliant example that can easily demonstrate the error, but if that's not available then show any code that's relevant to the error- in this case, it might be helpful if you show us what is supposed to set `RatePackages`.

Comment: RatePackages comes from here:                                   public class UpdateRatePackagesRequest
    {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;
        public UpdateRatePackageRequest[] RatePackages;


    } is that what you're asking? Its from what the user feeds in

Comment: I've worked with arrays, I've worked with webservices but this is the first time I'm having to use them together. Is there a way I can reflect in my code above where RatePackages should be coming from? Did I miss something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user1270384 That's the class that contains the `RatePacakges` field, so clear enough, but it seems that `UpdateRatePackagesRequest` is not properly populated. What might be helpful for you (rather than me) is if you can take a look at what's supposed to set the `RatePackages` field.

Comment: Is `UpdateRatePackagesRequest` a class that you've written? Where do you populate the `RatePackages` array?

Comment: No it belongs to the webservice that I am trying to send updates to.

Comment: I am trying to send a hardcoded message to the service before I can set how to populate. I am able to send to the service using a soap UI hence am trying to communicate with it via code before setting parameters etc, does that make sense?

Comment: @user1270384 I don't work with web services, so I can't really say if it makes sense or not, but if you think that it makes sense then maybe it does make sense ;). However, the point is that you need to look at what is supposed to populate `RatePackages` before you can use it in the for loop.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of populating an array so that I can match that to be sure its not the array I am going wrong with?

Comment: @user1270384 This should be pretty basic stuff... almost as basic as "hello world." At the very minimum, you should initialize your array, here is one way to initialize the array: `int[] numbers = new int[10];` Populating it is a matter of creating a for-loop `for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)` and storing a number in each element of the array.

Comment: ok that was a big help thanks, it turns out the problem is in initializing arrays that belong to a web service. Is there anybody on this forum that has knowledge of this?

Comment: Feel free to post another question that's more specific and remember to tag the question with the relevant tags (that will get more people to see it).